Jasper Reports - How to dynamically set PDF properties in .jrxml
Upon generating a PDF, I can specify the document's Title property in Java, like this...
jasperPrint.setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.metadata.title", "Report ID "+REPORT_ID);

Question:
How do I do the same thing in the .jrxml file instead, getting the ID from a value of a field in the data?
What I've tried:
Placing a <propertyExpression> with the other <property> tags sort-of works, but gives "Report ID null" (because it comes before the field declarations? Is that how jrxml works?):
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.metadata.title"><![CDATA["Report ID " + $F{REPORT_ID}]]></propertyExpression>

= "Report ID null"

When I move the <propertyExpression> tag beneath my field declarations, it throws an error that <propertyExpression> is not a valid tag (even though it's still a child of the root element):
<field name="REPORT_ID" class="java.lang.String"/>
...
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.metadata.title"><![CDATA["Report ID " + $F{REPORT_ID}]]></propertyExpression>


Error Reference :- 1716423819763 - : javax.ejb.EJBException:
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 232; columnNumber: 76;
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
element 'propertyExpression'. One of
'{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":variable,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":filterExpression,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":group,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":background,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":title,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageHeader,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnHeader,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":detail,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":columnFooter,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":pageFooter,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":lastPageFooter,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":summary,
"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":noData}' is
expected.


You should post a small snippet - looks like the jrxml file you tried to use is invalid

Set evaluationType="Report" for the property expression:
<propertyExpression name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.metadata.title" evaluationType="Report"><![CDATA["Report ID " + $F{REPORT_ID}]]></propertyExpression>

The property will be evaluated when the report ends and will use the last value of the REPORT_ID field.
